Where do I create my first circuit?
I want to get the result of this code:
qreg_a = QuantumRegister (2)
qreg_b = QuantumRegister (2)
creg = ClassicalRegister (4)
qc = QuantumCircuit(qreg_a,qreg_b,creg)
qc.x(qreg_a[0])
qc.measure(qreg_a,creg[0:2])
qc.measure(qreg_b,creg[2:4])
simulator= BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
result = execute(qc, simulator).result()
counts - result.get_counts(qc)

Quantum Lab has been discontinued. Where do I code this?

Google colab is one good option.
You will need to install Qiskit module(s) at the beginning, then you are ready:


Thank you so much for the help

Once you have the .qasm, you can also upload it to the Classiq platform https://platform.classiq.io/circuit, and then run it on a simulator.
To create your .qasm file (qiskit version 1.1) you will also need to have 'qiskit-qasm3-import' installed. Than use the following code:
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.providers.basic_provider import BasicProvider
import qiskit.qasm3

qreg_a = QuantumRegister (2)
qreg_b = QuantumRegister (2)
qc = QuantumCircuit(qreg_a,qreg_b)
qc.x(qreg_a[0])

with open("my_first_circuit.qasm","w") as my_file:
    qiskit.qasm3.dump(qc,my_file)

Upload the .qasm file to https://platform.classiq.io/circuit:

Then, press the "execute" button on the upper right hand side:

Choose a simulator on the left hand menu:

Press run, and you can get the histogram as well as download the results:

Disclaimer - I am a Classiq employee
